# Write to local.settings.json Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

Is there any way to update the local.settings.json in Azure Function pragmatically. I need the `TimerTrigger` configurable. I hope to keep that configuration in local.settings.json file. When user inputs a time from interface, the function should pragmatically update the configuration file.

Note - I am developing the function locally. Not from the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `local.settings.json` file should not be published to Azure, it's why it get's automatically added to the `.gitignore` file when the project is created. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file).

It can be configured by Environment variables (IIRC that is one of the recommended ways of pulling in configuration). That way it can easily be controlled by ARM templates or via the Azure Portal.

So you could easily use [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8).